# jquery mobile image width causes delayed loading of image on xcode iPhone (4.3.3)

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery 1.7.1 and jquery-mobile 1.1.0. And it's for iPhone (and iPad) devices - tested with xCode on Mac OS X.

I have a [MULTI page Template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) (not Simple Page):

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-start">
    <img src="src/images/header-img.png" style="max-width:100%;" />

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            Welcome to the test page<br/>
            now some test input fields:
        </p>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name2">Text Input:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my Problem is, the page is already displayed, but the image (origin width: 770px) is displayed with a delay of 2-3 seconds. Without the "max-width" or simple "width" style attribute it's displayed directly (but with a width of 770px).

How can I solve that the image is already loaded when the page is shown?

What I also tried is to hide the "#page-start" (with style="display:none" initially) and performed on javascript:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("#page-start").show();
});
```

but it didn't solve my problem, the page is displayed directly and the image takes 2,3,4 seconds until it's shown up and the page jumps down a bit (exatly the image height).

Comment: what is the size of your image

Comment: As I wrote "770px" ;-) But can be more, doesn't matter, should be a solution for any kind of width :-\ Thank you

Comment: Don't happens on a simple page, only multi page template!